# XNA remove shader effects

Tags: c#, xna

I am new to XNA 4.0 and I'm using a shader for my background texture that creates a glow effects on white objects. When I try to add sprites to the background image it also creates the glow on my sprites, how can I remove my shader on the sprites I add on top of my background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 seperate `SpriteBatch.Begin() ... SpriteBatch.End()` sections.
In the first use the `Effect` that wraps your shader and draw your background.
In the second draw anything you want without applying the shader.